# Floating-point format sequences in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I encountered some syntax during my studies that I do not understand.

```
puts "He is %d (%3.2f in floating point terms) pounds heavy." % [weight, weight]
```

The one thing I am not understanding about this is the purpose of `3.2`. 
Thanks for taking a look!

P.S. By the way the `weight` variable was originally defined in pounds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `%n.mf` format means the *entire* output field width is `n` character positions, and the number of places shown after the decimal point is `m`, with blank padding in front of the number if necessary to complete the entire field with of `n`. The decimal is padded right with `0`s if needed to bring the number of visible decimal places up to `m`.

So the value `23.12` with a format of `%8.3f` will show as `bb23.120` (where each `b` is a blank, not really a `b`). A format of `%8.1f` would yield `bbbb23.1`. A format of `%8.0f` would give `bbbbbb23`.

Note that if the formatted number would be more characters than the requested entire field width, then the field will just be made bigger to accommodate the number, so it's not truncated. In the above example, a format of `%3.2f` for `23.12` would give `23.12`.

For the `%3.2f` case, the field width is given as `3` with `2` digits after the decimal point. Since `2` decimal places plus the decimal point already consume `3` character positions, any float printed with this format will be printed in their entirety with no preceding blanks. You'd get the same result with `%2.2f` or `%1.2f` or `%0.2f`. However this format will always give `2` decimal places either truncating or zero-padding if needed to make it exactly `2` visible digits.

Answer (score 0):

We can specify the number of decimal places we want like this: %0.2f.

The 2 here indicates that we want to keep only two decimal places.

Here is an example:
score = 78.5431
puts "The average is %0.2f" % [score]

Output => The average is 78.54